# How to access Local file in Python from Website

Tags: python, django, heroku

I was able to access local file in local host by using the code

**'src = path.realpath("C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\imp.txt")**

but as I hosted it on heroku it shows error of
**file not found '/app/C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\imp.txt'**

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
print(str(os.path.join('C:','Users','HP','AppData','Local','imp.txt')))
src = str(os.path.join('C:','Users','HP','AppData','Local','imp.txt'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much that idea works partly.But now I have issue of OperationalError
  unable to open database file can you please help me

Comment: i would ask that as a separate question and mark this complete

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.